# Modifying abstract method

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Is it possible to modify or extend the content of a method of an abstract class?

```
public abstract class MainClass{
    public void func(){
        // content...
    }
}

public class FirstClass extends MainClass{
    public void func(){
        // content from MainClass
        // own content
    }
}
public class SecondClass extends MainClass{
    public void func(){
        // content from MainClass
        // other content
    }
}
```

I need the method `func` in both classes, but with a small modification.

Comment: An `abstract` method doesn't have "content", by definition.

Comment: Did you even tried to compile the code before posting

Comment: @sol4me: This is kind of "pseudo code"

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But OP didn't say "an abstract method", but "a method of an abstract class". Abstract classes can have non-abstract methods.

Comment: @DavidConrad See _@SotiriosDelimanolis: Ok, edited.  –  user1170330_

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
public abstract void func(){
    // content...
}
```

cannot exist as an abstract method has no body. If you had an abstract method with a body, it would be a compile-time error.

However, you can always [call the superclass method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

```
public class MainClass{
    public void func(){
        // base content...
    }
}

public class FirstClass extends MainClass{
    public void func(){
        super.func();
        // own content
    }
}
public class SecondClass extends MainClass{
    public void func(){
        super.func();
        // other content
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case the whole method from `MainClass` would be executed. I need to modify some parts of the method first, before executing.

Comment: @user1170330 That is not consistent with the code samples given in your original post. Without breaking apart the super class method and calling it part by part, that is not possible.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't contain any abstract methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could find interesting the use of Template method pattern. Probably it solution your problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

```
public abstract class MainClass {

    public final void sharingcode() {
        // content from MainClass
        // write here the common code

        concreteCode(); // Calling abstract method to be implemented by implementations
    }

    protected abstract void concreteCode();

    public class FirstClass extends MainClass {

        @Override
        public void concreteCode() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }

    public class SecondClass extends MainClass {

        @Override
        public void concreteCode() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think the Template method pattern is more preferable than calling super.  With this pattern, the extending class doesn't even need to worry about remembering, or forgetting, to call super.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify or extend a content of a method, no matter abstract class or not. You can override a method - i.e. provide new method implementation; you can also call "original" method from the parent class by using `super` keyword: `super.originalMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ezequiel is the best answer here, but wanted to present the Strategy Pattern as another option.  You basically forgo subclassing, and inject the difference in behaviour into MainClass:

```
public abstract class MainClass{
    private final Behaviour behaviour;

    public MainClass(Behaviour behaviour) {
        this.behaviour = behaviour;
    }

    public void func(){
        // content...
        behaviour.execute();
    }
}

public interface Behaviour {
    void execute();
}
```